# Error creating dynamically RequestParam URL with Thymeleaf

Tags: html, image, thymeleaf

I have a Spring MVC Server and the HTML pages are using  Thymeleaf.

I pass a `List<String>` as a ModelAndView Object to the page and the Thymeleaf gets the object correctly.

I am using `th:each` to make one URL for each String from the List to load a image from the server.

The Page Code is:

> ```
> <tr th:each="images_path : ${images_paths}">
>     <img class="picture" th:attr="src=@{'/image/'(id=${images_path})}" />
> </tr>
> ```

Where `image_paths` is the List with all the path of each image.

The result of processing that Thymeleaf Code I wish is (imaging I have to images_path in the images_path object ("path_image_one" and "path_image_two") (1):

> ```
> <img class="picture" src="/image/?id=path_image_one">
> <img class="picture" src="/image/?id=path_image_two">
> ```

But unluckily they appear together:

> ```
> <img class="picture" src="/image/?id=path_image_one&id=path_image_two">
> ```

How I could separate in two different images with two different URL as I typed above(1)?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that i didn't create an index variable to go over the hole List.

So I solved with that:

```
        <tr th:each="images_pat,row : ${images_path}" >
       <td><img class="picture" th:src="@{/image/(id=${images_path[row.index]})}" />
      </td>
```

Where row is a "variable" which has a special issue, it handles the index count.